# How to run each task in async and wait for all task to complete

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to run several tasks in async and wait for all of them to complete.

```
private static Task AddAFavicon(int id)
{
    // some operation where each task create excel sheet as per id.
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // i have this main method which contain publications in list 
    XElement Publication = XElement.Load() // read publication from xml file.
    foreach (var item in Publication.Descendants())
    {
        //here i want to call this AddAFavicon method for each item as async task 
    }
    //wait for all task to complete 
}
```

I want to wait for all tasks to complete and then do my other stuff.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0

Comment: What is the reason for doing this? Do you want to create multiple Excel files in parallel, for better performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-7.0) to wait for multiple async tasks to complete:

```
Task t1 = DoSomethingAsync1();
Task t2 = DoSomethingAsync2();
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
```

In your specific case you can do something like:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var item in Publication.Descendants())
{
    int id = 0; // TODO: Initialize properly.
    tasks.Add(AddAFavicon(id));
}
await Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: hi thanks for valuable reply can please show how i can apply your code in my sample code :(

Comment: You are planning to call `AddAFavicon` in the loop. Each call will return a `Task` object. Keep them all in a list/array and then use `Task.WhenAll` to wait for them all to complete.

Comment: I replaced the "cold" tasks with an example more compliant with the OP's code.

Answer (score -2):

You can do `await AddAFavIconAsync();` in your loop. It will wait for your current task to complete before going on the next item and doing the same action.

Note your code here is incomplete, an `async` function should have the `async` keyword in its declaration, if not you will not be able to await anything inside that method.

So you would have something more like :

```
private static async Task AddAFaviconAsync(int id)
{
    // some operation where each task create excel sheet as per id.
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // i have this main method which contain publications in list 
    XElement Publication = XElement.Load() // read publication from xml file.
    foreach (var item in Publication.Descendants())
        {
            await AddAFavIconAsync(item.id);
            //here i want to call this AddAFavicon method for each item as async task 
        }
}
```

You can also note that I added `Async` at the end of the method names. Its just a basic naming convention you should use :). Just not for the Main method ([as shown here](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/async-main-csharp/)).

Comment: You could, but since you await each task you are not doing them asynchronously.

Comment: @Taemyr Yes you _are_ doing them asynchronously but not _concurrently_.

Comment: @Fildor what's the difference between thoses two (asynchronously and concurrently) ?
I also feel like I misunderstood the question, my bad.

Comment: @Scryper : https://medium.com/plain-and-simple/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-vs-concurrent-vs-parallel-4342bfb8b9f2

Comment: No.  You are adding a synchronization instruction (the await) between the tasks.  So you are saying, start task 1, when that is finished start task 2, and so on.  I.e. synchronously.  Rather than start task 1 and task 2 and so on, and then waiting for all of them to finish.  Your outer method returns a task, so you can do other things asynchronously with this method, but the method you have written runs synchronously.

Comment: No, @Taemyr. `await` does a lot more than that. It may or may not (assuming this is a "real" IO-Bound operation: it will) release the current Thread to do other things, waiting for the completion of the Task. That's the whole idea of that and **a**synchronous. Otherwise we just could have stuck to plain old Threads.

Comment: Oh _that's_ what you mean ... it's still not synchronous. That would just be sequential.

Comment: Agreed there is more going on, this does not change the fact that the method as written synchronizes it's tasks.

Comment: It's sequential, yes. But it does not block (the thread).

Comment: Yes, you avoid blocking.  But given that we see main I am not sure there is any benefit. (Nothing else for the thread to do)

Comment: Right. That's why OP seems to target for both: asynchronity _and_ concurrency. :D

Comment: @Taemyr `async` / `await` makes the code _read_ like synchronous code. Once compiled, it is actually asynchronous.